# CSS Outline Around Shapes

Tags: html, css, shapes, box-shadow

I have the following code in my CSS and HTML files:

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 60px 0px white, inset 200px 0px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

The shape this code produces is exactly what I want; however, I do not want the blue outline around the white part - is there anyway I can remove that?

To further clarify: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtUGV.png) is what the shape currently looks like on a white background, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mStBV.png) is how I would like it to look like.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I do not want the blue outline around the white part" -- sorry but I can't imagine the expected behaviour. Can you post an expected-behaviour-picture?

Comment: @shaochuancs updated the post a current-behavior and expected-behavior picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a trick, to overlay a 2px white border over it is acceptable.

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 60px 0px 0px 0 white, inset 200px 0px 5px blue;
  position:relative;
}
.test:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid white;
  z-index:1;
  top:-1px;
  right:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is doing exactly what I wanted - I have marked this as the best answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Tell us what you want to achieve so we can know how to help you achieve it.
This little change made the blue outline go away and left you circle looking like eclipse

```
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 60px 0px white, inset 10px 0px blue;
}
```

Comment: Due to my lack of reputation, I can only post two links. After adding the before/after photos, I had to remove the JSFiddle link.

Comment: I tried it many times in the jfiddle but cant get it like you wanted. The thing is that the shadows are inset so the borders can never be gotten rid of except you make it transparent which cant get the shape you wanted. So i suggest you use image to achieve this. If you have image that shape you can set it as background for the <div class="test"></div> tag